# How to left align title in navigation header in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native

tThis is my code in the navigator:

```
<Tab.Screen
    name="Profile"
    component={Profile}
    options={{
      title: username,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleAlign: 'left',
      },
      headerTintColor: 'black',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
    }}
  />
```

We want to mimic instagram's header on iOS where the username is on the top left corner of the header.

We currently getting a console warning message stating headertitleAlign was given a value of left, this has no effect on headerstyle.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`headerTitleAlign` is not a valid style property. That shouldn't be given inside the `headerStyle`. Simply move `headerTitleAlign:'left'` outside of the `headerStyle` property and it should work.

```js
<Tab.Screen
    name="Profile"
    component={Profile}
    options={{
      title: username,
      headerTitleAlign: 'left', //moved this from headerStyle property
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
      },
      headerTintColor: 'black',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
    }}
/>
```

Comment: why the `headerTitleAlign: 'left'` isn't working for me on iOS?

Comment: Super weird. Documentation says it defaults to left on platforms other than ios. Yet it's center on android. And it's always center on iOS. lol

Answer (score 1):

You do indeed want `headerTitleAlign: 'left'` in the main body of the `options` object, as @nithinpp mentioned. Note, however, that this setting won't do anything on iOS, as the [documentation disappointingly notes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#headertitlealign).

If you'd like it to work on iOS as well, you'll need to provide your own `headerTitle` component:

```js
<Tab.Screen
  name="Profile"
  component={Profile}
  options={{
    title: username,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    headerTintColor: 'black',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    headerTitle: props => (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <Text>
          {props.children}
        </Text>
      </View>
    ),
  }}
/>
```

Note in this case that I'm just proposing you use a `flexDirection: "row"` on a View in order to left-justify. You can alternatively do whatever you want within headerTitle to get the effect you want.